# Получить набор объектов текущей страницы dirPagination + AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, pagination

Необходимо получить набор объектов на странице (не весь набор, а только отображаемый на текущей странице), при использовании dirPagination в AngularJS 1.5.
ng-inspector кроме основного набора ничего не показывает.
По мысли идут в сторону дополнительного аналогичного фильтра, но как реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Очень трудно переходить на парадигму работы с объектами со стороны JS.
Решение оказалось легкое и простое:

```
 $scope.pageItems = function () {
        var start= ($scope.Items.length > $scope.itemsPerPage ? $scope.itemsPerPage : 0) * ($scope.currentPage - 1);
        var end = ($scope.Items.length > $scope.itemsPerPage ? $scope.itemsPerPage : $scope.Items.length) * ($scope.currentPage);
        return $scope.Items.slice(start, end );
    }
```

`$scope.Items` - Все пришедшие данные.
`$scope.pageItems` - Все текущие ОТОБРАЖАЕМЫЕ данные.